# Pasar de mayusculas a minusculas las dos primeras letras en un campo de MySql

Tags: mysql

Consulta sobre como pasar de mayúsculas a minúsculas las dos primeras letras del campo **email** en MySql en la sintaxis:

```
select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName, 1),LastName,'@miempresa.com') as email from employees
```

Pero me lista el **email** con las dos primeras letras en mayúscula y todo debe estar en minúscula: **NDavolio@miempresa.com**' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo quieres todo en minúscula puedes utilizar la función LOWER

```
select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, LOWER(CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName, 
1),LastName,'@miempresa.com')) as email from employees
```

Comment: Super!!! mil gracias.

Comment: @maikervasquez, ¿Solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!